# Ratio of workloads in the 2 projects

Tags: contest-math, word-problem, ratio

The ratio of the numbers of the workers in teams of X and Y is 3:4, and the ratio of the working efficiencies for the workers in teams X and Y is 5:4. Both teams do the projects in which the workload and the conditions are identical. However, Y finishes the project 9 days earlier than X. Later, two new teams are composed. M consists of *2/3*of the workers in X and *1/3* of the workers in Y, and N consist of the rest of workers in both X and Y. Both teams (M and N) do the projects in which the work load and the conditions are identical. However, N finishes the project six days earlier than M. What is the ratio of the workloads in the two projects

I am having trouble answering this question, and I don't have any work to show. Hints or solution is welcome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let the total number of workers be W
Number of workers in X = 3/7 W
Number of workers in Y = 4/7 W

Let the efficiency of a worker in X be E units of work per day
Efficiency of a worker in Y = 4/5 E

Let t days be taken by Y to complete the project and t+9 be taken by X

Since workloads is the same in both projects undertaken by X and Y,
{Number of workers x Efficiency of a worker x Time in days} is the same for both X and Y

**Equation 1:**
**3/7 W E (t+9) = 4/7 W 4/5 E t**

After the new teams M and N are formed, we can assume that the efficiency of each worker remains the same in the newly formed teams also.

For the newly assigned projects to M and N, let us assume that N completes the work in t' days. M completes it in (t' + 6) days

Since the workloads for the newly assigned projects to M and N are the same, we have:

**Equation 2: {2/3 (3/7 W E) + 1/3 (4/7 W 4/5 E)} (t'+6) = {1/3 (3/7 W E) + 2/3 (4/7 W 4/5 E)} t'**

You can solve Equation 1 to find t. You can solve equation 2 to find t'

**Ratio of the workload in the two projects = [3/7 W E (t+9)] / [{2/3 (3/7 W E) + 1/3 (4/7 W 4/5 E)} (t'+6)]**

Since t and t' are known and W and E can be cancelled, you can then calculate this ratio.

You can also look at this infographic [[Source](https://learningpundits.com/module-view/43-ratios-and-proportions/1-tips-on-ratios-and-proportions/)] to help you understand similar word problems on Ratios and Proportions.

[Infographic on solving Aptitude Problems in Ratios and Proportions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3bBS.png)